# How can I expose rest service xsd to clients

Tags: rest, xsd, xsd-validation, swagger

I have developed a rest api and using swagger for creating api docs. I want to expose an xsd to validate the rest service output and also clients will be able to use it to generate classes. What is best way to expose xsd to client? Can I use swagger to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Swagger doesn't support XSD directly. Swagger 2.0 has some extended support for XML modeling using the `xml` property.

However, with Swagger 2.0 you can also reference an external doc, which you could potentially link to the XSD, and use that as a basis for your tools.